# nslookup awk to a file showing "answer"

Tags: awk, nslookup

I am currently running a script that uses nslookup on a bunch of hosts and then uses awk to print desired lines into a table. I am printing one line to file1 and another to file2, then using `paste file1 file2 >> file3` to produce this table.

The table looks like this

```
Host   IP
name  10.10.10.10
name  10.10.10.10
name 10.10.10.10
```

For the most part, this is working. But for some reason, about 20 of my 160 results are getting "answer:" in the left column, and the hostname is appearing in the right. Like this:

```
Host IP
answer:  hostname
```

This is showing up randomly throughout the results and I can't figure it out because the nslookup doesn't have the word "answer:" in it anywhere for the script to accidentally awk.

Here is my script for reference:

```
hosts='hosts.list'
filelines=`cat $hosts`

Empty_Containers(){
        truncate -s 0 tmp.txt
        truncate -s 0 file1
        truncate -s 0 file2
}

for h in $filelines ;
do
        Empty_Containers
        nslookup $h > tmp.txt
        if grep -q "NXDOMAIN" tmp.txt
        then
                cat tmp.txt | awk 'FNR ==4 {print$5}' > file1
                echo "Did_Not_Resolve" > file2
                paste file1 file2 >> i.txt
        else
                cat tmp.txt | awk 'FNR ==4 {print$2}' > file1
                cat tmp.txt |awk 'FNR ==5 {print$2}' > file2
                paste file1 file2 >> i.txt
        fi
        cat i.txt | column -t 2 i.txt
done
```

Comment: Is there some reason you're not just using one `awk` script to print the output you desire rather than this Rube Goldberg machine?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Probably because I couldn't figure out how to awk 2 separate outputs. I figured out my problem, but I wouldn't mind if you showed me a better way to do it.

Comment: This doesn't even use `awk`; I was able to just do `for h in $(cat hosts.list); do a=$(dig +short $h | head -n1); echo -e "$h\t${a:-Did Not Resolve}"; done` to seemingly get your desired result.

Comment: Welp. that replaced all my work pretty easily. Could you explain your script? also, I'm still getting the same "answer:" problem with it due to an extra line in the nslookup that says "Non-authoritative answer". How would you fix that?

Comment: I went into detail in my answer.  If you have further questions, I'm happy to explain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your desired goal is to just make a table of hostnames and IP addresses, and you don't care particularly about using `nslookup`, I was able to seemingly create your desired output with a quick `for .. echo` loop:

```
for h in $( cat hosts.list ); do
    a=$(dig +short $h | head -n1)
    echo -e "$h\t${a:-Did_Not_Resolve}"
done
```

`dig` is a slightly more friendly-to-scripting DNS tool than is `nslookup`, using the `+short` option makes the output even cleaner.  The output of a request for which there is no record is an empty string, so I use the built-in `bash` default parameter expansion (`${var:-default}`) to handle the case of no record giving a "default" answer of `Did_Not_Resolve`.

```
$ dig www.example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> www.example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23579
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.example.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.example.com.    20308   IN  A   93.184.216.34

;; Query time: 28 msec
;; SERVER: 172.28.8.1#53(172.28.8.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Jun 01 12:02:27 MST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 60

$ dig +short www.example.com
93.184.216.34
```

The ultimate yield is this output:

```
www.example.com 93.184.216.34
www.google.com  172.217.14.68
host.doesnotexist.tld   Did_Not_Resolve
unix.stackexchange.com  151.101.129.69
```

An alternative to `dig` is also `host`:

```
$ for h in $(cat hosts.list); do host $h; done
www.example.com has address 93.184.216.34
www.example.com has IPv6 address 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
www.google.com has address 216.58.193.196
www.google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:4007:80d::2004
Host host.doesnotexist.tld not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
unix.stackexchange.com has address 151.101.129.69
unix.stackexchange.com has address 151.101.1.69
unix.stackexchange.com has address 151.101.65.69
unix.stackexchange.com has address 151.101.193.69
```

In response to the questions in the comment below:

The only option I use for `dig` is `+short`, which reduces the output to either the IP address for the given host, or an empty string otherwise.  I run `dig` in a subshell (`$( dig [...] )`) because I am capturing its output and assigning it to the variable `a` (for "address").  I am piping the output of `dig` through `head -n1` as some hosts (like the host `unix.stackexchange.com` return multiple IP addresses; for the sake of simplicity, I simply grab the first one.

The reason this is being pulled out into a variable is so that we can use a simple parameter expansion trick to provide the "Did not resolve" text in lieu of an empty string, as described previously herein.

Expanding as requested on the `echo` statement specifically:

```
echo -e "$h\t${a:-Did_Not_Resolve}"
```

- The `-e` switch tells `echo` that I will be using **e**scape sequences.  In this case, I am using `\t` which, when combined with `-e`, becomes a <kbd>Tab</kbd> rather than a literal escaped `t`.
- `$h` is, as you would expect, simply replaced with the contents of the variable `h`.
- `\t`, as explained earlier, becomes a Tab.
- `${a:-Did_Not_Resolve}`.  Ah, here's where the magic is.  `bash` has the ability when doing parameter expansion to do a little introspection as part of the process.  The syntax `${var:-default}` expands to the contents of the variable `var` *or*, if that is either unset or null, the provided replacement (in this example case, `default`; or in the actual use case here, `Did_Not_Resolve`).  You can find more details about this in the `bash` manual page, in the section labeled "Parameter Expansion".

The end result of this is outputting on each line, in the following order, the hostname, a <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and either the address if there was one, or the text `Did_Not_Resolve` if there was not.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. You can probably tell I'm a bash beginner, so could you explain your dig options to me better? particularly the "head -n1" and the need for a=$(...)

Comment: Scratch that, I've figured that stuff out. Can you explain your syntax in the echo command further?

Comment: I have gone into detail about the particulars of the `echo` invocation.